# Adding order to a relation makes relation saving fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, given these two models:

```
class Solution < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, -> { order(name: :asc) }
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :solution
end
```

This code will fail with `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Tasks is invalid`:

```
solution = Solution.new(name: "My Solution", tasks: [
  Task.new(name: "My Task")
])

solution.save!
```

This is due to the task's `solution` being `nil`:

```
(byebug) pp solution.tasks[0].errors.messages
{:solution=>["must exist"]}
```

However, when removing the order from the `has_many` clause (into just `has_many :tasks`), it works fine:

```
(byebug) pp solution.tasks[0].solution == nil
false
```

Is this expected?

Example project (look at the last two commits): https://github.com/hannesstruss/test_order_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`inverse_of`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) fixes it:

```
has_many :tasks, -> { order(name: :asc) }, inverse_of: :solution
```

and

```
belongs_to :problem, inverse_of: :tasks
```